# Troubles with MySQL open_files_limit

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Ubuntu 16.04.2. MySQL 5.7.17.

During peek hours, my PHP sites suffer fatal error trying to connect to MySQL. Apache says

> Error 24 Out of resources when opening file

Ok makes sense, I get lots of traffic. I read up, and seems my `open_files_limit` var of `1,024` is too small (it really is seeing `5000` is default).

So after some reading, I ran `mysql --verbose --help | less` to find which config files I should go to. It gave me:

> Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
>   /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

But, `/etc/my.cnf` and `~/.my.cnf` didn't exist.

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` did, and it looks exactly like this:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

When I appended `open_files_limit = 2084` to the above `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file. I was unable to `sudo service mysql start` MySQL. I had to remove the line, then I could start MySQL.

The only other MySQL configuration file I could find was `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and I tried adding the `open_files_limit` line there and restarted, it restarted but the variable didn't chang.

What am I doing wrong? What do I do to increase my `open_files_limit`?

---

**UPDATE**

Seems the place to change the value was in `/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service`

Had to add `LimitNOFILE=infinity` save, then `systemctl daemon-reload`

There's lots of readings on the reasonings for this for some setups, and reasons not to use infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your db architecture. If you have many tables in separate files in the MyISAM, ARIA, or Innodb with files per table you will want a higher open file limit. If you have everything in the Innodb / xtradb in a single tablespace then upping your file limits will not benefit.

Check current system limits

```
ulimit -a
```

Temporary limit increase

```
ulimit -n 65535
```

Permanent update /etc/security/limits.conf

The mysql open file limit can't exceed system limits.

```
* soft nofile 65535
* hard nofile 65535
```

Comment: I not 100% sure why, but in some cases * not help for me, changing * for mysql resolve situation

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did that, restarted everything, and `ulimit -a` showed proper new 2048 number. However, `open_files_limit` did not change, it's still caped at 1024.

I received in mysql/error.log: **[Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 1024 (request: 4161)**

Comment: More reading. Seems like I have to next edit `/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service` adding `LimitNOFILE=infinity` then `systemctl daemon-reload` and restart mysql. I will try that this evening.

Comment: Confirmed. Above finally changed that number. I guess `infinity` = `65,536`, which is what `open_files_limit` now is

Answer (score 0):

Once you have changed the ulimit in the OS, change/add

```
[mysqld]
open_file_slimit = 2048
```

and restart.

Note:  it must be in the `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf` (or whichever file).